# Jquery POST fetching data on keyup

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**What I want to do**

When writing in the text field, I want the `<div class="result">` to be filled with what PHP is echoing.

But it doesn't work!

*Jquery*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var search = $("#search");
    if (search.val() !== '') {
        search.keyup(function() {
            $.post("index.php", { search : search.val()}, function(data) {
                $(".result").html(data);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

*php*

```
    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
        echo 'hello';
    }
```

*html*

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search"/>
<br />
<div class="result"></div>
```

**Problem**

When filling the input, nothing happens, and it meant to POST the entered data on keyup (When entering a new character/or deleting.

What is stopping it from working? I am new to jQuery .

Thanks.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is wrong.

```
if (search.val() !== '') {
```

The above line should be,

```
if (search.val() != '') {
```

**EDIT:**

Then wrap the if condition inside the keyup function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var search = $("#search");

        search.keyup(function() {
            if (search.val() != '') {
                $.post("getInputs.php", { search : search.val()}, function(data) {
                    $(".result").html(data);
                });
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: @JonyKale Found your problem. You need wrap the if condition inside the keyup() function. Try that. it will work

Comment: Oh.. I get this now.
Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 2):

When I run into situations like this, I just start breaking the problem in half to see where its failing. Here are a couple things I would try.

First, in your jQuery, add some output to the console:

```
if (search.val() !== '') {
        console.log("I am not empty so I should go to index.php");
        search.keyup(function() {
            $.post("index.php", { search : search.val()}, function(data) {
                $(".result").html(data);
            });
        });
    } 
else
{
     console.log("search val was empty");
}
```

Of course you could always check the browsers network profiler to see if it made a POST to that resource. This will tell you if the problem is in your `search.val` test.

Then, if you want to debug the PHP side, you could remove the `isset` test and just always return "hello".  That will tell you if its an issue with your POST variables or checks.

Finally, you could output the data result to be sure something is coming back at all. This will remove any issues with `$(".result").html()` being the problem:

```
$.post("index.php", { search : search.val()}, function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   $(".result").html(data);
});
```

If none of these work, maybe you could just switch around the way you bind to `keyup` in the first place:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").keyup(function() {
       if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            $.post("index.php", { search : $(this).val()}, function(data) {
                $(".result").html(data);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var search = $("#search");


});
```

This fire only at document ready but not on keyup, means in var $("#search").val() will be blank.

Change your code to capture inpute value on every key-up stroke.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         search.keyup(function() {

             var value = $("#search").val();
             if(value!="")
            {
             $.post("index.php", { search : value}, function(data) {
                $(".result").html(data);
            });
           }
        });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it still doesn't do anything

Comment: This is incorrect. You don't need to have jquery find a DOM element and craft an object every time. A reference to it is fine and a current value should be returned when you ask for it.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: search is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is incorrect. You are only setting the keyup event handler if your #search has text in it. Unfortunately when that script runs on document ready, there is NO value in #search so your keyup handler never gets set, which is why it never fires.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote some of your logic and was able to get it to work. One being the way your checking to ensure you have a value. Instead of string comparing I am checking the length. Also, instead of binding the event to the field, I bind the event on the document and target the field. Try it:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="search" id="search"/>
<br />
<div class="result"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('keyup', 'input#search', function() {
            if($(this).val().length > 0) {
                $.post('index.php', {"search":$(this).val()}, function(data) {
                    $('div.result').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// when the html is loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
    // find an element with the id 'search'
    var search = $("#search");

    // if this element's value is NOT an empty string -- oh look, it is!
    if (search.val() !== '') {
        // well, going to skip all this here then
        search.keyup(function() { // don't care
            $.post("index.php", { search : search.val()}, function(data) { // don't care
                $(".result").html(data); // don't care
            });
        });
    }

    // YAAAAY! All done!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually nothing is wrong in your code. I have tried your code itself. Only issue was that you have called keyup function conditionally. Your Javascript code should be like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var search = $("#search");
        search.keyup(function() {
            if (search.val() != '') {       
            $.post("index.php", { search : search.val()}, function(data) {
                $(".result").html(data);
            });
            }
        });

});
```

Here, condition should be inside the keyup function.